# How to mock API's before launching the UI test?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I want to mock the API response before the activity launch to test the real-time scenario. I am using rxjava with viewmodel to make the API calls in actual activity class. I have created a custom dispatcher to mock the API calls and calling it in BaseUItest class. But this process is not working when i launch the test as i see no data is loading up and no mock API call is being made. Here's the BaseUItest:

```
open class BaseUITest {
    protected var mockWebServer = MockWebServer()

    @Before
    open fun setup() {
        mockWebServer.start(5000)
        mockWebServer.dispatcher = ApiDispatcher()
    }

    @After
    open fun teardown() {
        mockWebServer.shutdown()
    }
}
```

Do i need to mock viewmodels too before mocking the API's? What I am doing here? Please help.

Comment: Is you code complete ? https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver from this example, I think you need to ask the server for it's url and pass it to your handling class... I guess..

Comment: @sak: Did you achieve what you were doing? I am stuck in the same scenario and not able to have a direction. Can you help out?

Comment: @MonsterBrain Not able to understand by asking the server. Do I have to mention the endpoint path I want to mock or the baseURL of my server

Comment: @Emjey Yes. You can get the url of endpoint by passing the server.url("your/api/endpoint") function ... more details in the answer

Answer (score 0):

In the dispatcher you need to check for the end point, and produce your own mock response for this mock server. For example.

```
val server = MockWebServer()

val dispatcher: Dispatcher = object : Dispatcher() {
            @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
            override fun dispatch(request: RecordedRequest): MockResponse? {
                when (request.path) {
                    "/v1/login/auth/" -> return MockResponse().setResponseCode(200)
                    "/v1/profile/info" -> return MockResponse().setResponseCode(200)
                        .setBody("{\"info\":{\"name\":\"Lucas Albuquerque\",\"age\":\"21\",\"gender\":\"male\"}}")
                }
                return MockResponse().setResponseCode(404)
            }
        }
        server.setDispatcher(dispatcher)
```

In the calling section you can get the endpoint url by

```
fun getUrl(): HttpUrl {
    return server.url("/v1/profile/info")
}
```

Which will return the server response with json body as mentioned in the dispatcher.